# ChartJs not Rendering

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bootstrap-5, popover, mdbootstrap

So I am trying to render a chart inside of a bootstrap popover and it doesn't seem to be rendering. I have tried every possible thing to debug, but I can't quite figure out what's wrong. So any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my html code:

```
<div id="popover-content" style="display: none;">
      {%include 'scroll_card.html'%}
    </div>
```

note: I am using jinja to render my html code which contains the graph that I would like to show in my popover. Below is what's in the scroll_card.html file

```
  <div class='summary'><h5 class='header'> Chart </h5>
        <div class="chart" style="height: 400px;">
        <canvas id='hourly-chart' width="300" height="400">Hello</canvas></div>
    </div>
```

And my js code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const myPopoverTrigger = document.getElementById('popover');
let hourChart =null;
const instance = new mdb.Popover(myPopoverTrigger, {
    title:"Hourly Forecast",
    sanitize:false,
    html:true,
    content: function(){
        popContent = document.querySelector('#popover-content').innerHTML;
        return popContent;
    }
    
});


myPopoverTrigger.addEventListener('show.mdb.popover', () => {
    const ctxHour = document.getElementById('hourly-chart').getContext('2d');
    console.log(ctxHour);
    if (hourChart) {
            hourChart.destroy();
        }
hourChart = new Chart(ctxHour, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    
    });
    console.log(hourChart);
});
    myPopoverTrigger.addEventListener('hide.mdb.popover', () => {
        if (hourChart) {
            hourChart.destroy();
        }

    });
});
```

Another Note: when I use my console.log the chart (hourChart), it returns a chart object in the console which gives some weird attributes, like in the options, it returned x and y as undefined. Could I be doing something wrong or missing something?

Thanks

Edit:

So here is my console when I do console.log(hourChart).

[image: Console Output]

Comment: With the  Inspect/Elements, do you see the canvas element and if you do,  are its computed sizes OK (large enough to be seen)?

Comment: They were not at first, then I did some research and saw something about making responsive false which then solved it and then I began seeing the width and height values as the one I specified but then no chart got rendered

Comment: You may use `responsive: true`, which allows you to set the css width and height of the containing div and set none of the canvas properties [see docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note). The issue, is, as I said in the message below, that you duplicated the `id`s, so `document.getElementById('hourly-chart')` retrieved the original, hidden canvas from `popover-content` and not the newly created one for the popup. You have to find a way to avoid that.

Comment: Failing to aquire context usually means that the canvas does not exist. Log what exactly is returned by the `getElementsByClassName` and see if there are two elements. Anyway, the class solution is one of many possible solutions, probably not the best. Another, for instance, is to modify the id of the canvas in the html that is injected in the popup, like in [this example](https://www.codeply.com/p/m3CTCJKxGI). You may also choose to delete the html from the `popover-content` div when you put in in the popup, and then set it back when the popup closes.

Comment: Still did not work but I see something interesting now, which is if you look at my updated question, you'll see an image of my console output for the chart, We can see that it is rendering it, but not rendering it completely. Like if you take a look at legend option in the console you'll see x is undefined and y is also undefined, title block is undefined, tooltip is also undefined.

Comment: No, that is not a problem, most legends don't have `x` and `y` set, those are supplemental/alternative  positioning properties, what counts is `left`, `right`, `top`, `width` etc. and those are probably set. This looks like an OK chart to me, I don't know why it's not visible. Can you explore the `canvas` parent chain to see if this is the canvas that is inside the popup?

Comment: @kikon it works!!!! I have just realised maybe programming isn't for me . So what I did actually was to rewrite the whole thing again and now it works. So maybe I did overlook something. Could you post your answer with the custom Id's so that I can accept it as the answer because that's what I'm using. The classes solution also works. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML content should be provided directly in the option. Otherwise it's not being added to the DOM in time for the canvas/chart to render.

```
const instance = new mdb.Popover(myPopoverTrigger, {
        title: "Hourly Forecast",
        sanitize: false,
        html: true,
        content: `<div id="popover-content">
                <div class='summary'>
                    <h5 class='header'> Chart </h5>
                    <div class="chart" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;">
                        <canvas id='hourly-chart' width="600" height="400"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`

    });
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/uxPMnF28ET

Comment: Now the thing is, I have a lot of html code in that scroll_card.html, and I also have some jinja in there too for parsing some data, so is there any other way I could do it such that I wouldn’t have to add all the html code into content, maybe like a wait for popover to load before charts loading?

Comment: Your solution is correct, but the explanation is that OP's approach duplicates the elements with the same id, so the canvas obtained by `document.getElementById('hourly-chart')` is not the new one, but the hidden one. Here's a [fork](https://www.codeply.com/p/LgG0nU1HEx) that uses classes to identify the canvas(es) and filters by `offsetParent` to get the one that is visible, and works with html obtained as the OP did, in the `content` function.

Comment: @kikon I did take a look at your codeply and what I saw did make sense to me but then it's still not working locally for me, In the console, it's saying the chart can't acquire context which is probably because of the switch to using classes instead of Id, but it works on the codeply. which is sort of confusing to me